# Error starting Ejabberd 13.12 server on CentOS 6.5

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I rebooted my system and now I am having issues starting my ejabberd server on CentOS 6.5.
The tail of my ejabberd.log file is as follows:

```
[{mod_proxy65,start,2,[{file,"src/mod_proxy65.erl"},{line,48}]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,70}]},
 {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1323}]},
 {ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,67}]},
 {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                     [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]
2014-07-02 20:38:41.060 [critical] <0.37.0>@gen_mod:start_module:83 ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
2014-07-02 20:38:41.066 [error] <0.413.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.413.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: {eaddrnotavail,{6879,{192,168,1,125},tcp}} in ejabberd_listener:socket_error/6 line 539
```

I have made changes to the modules but have used make to compile them and it throws no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This is the core of the error message:

```
{eaddrnotavail,{6879,{192,168,1,125},tcp}}
```

That is, ejabberd tried to listen on port 6879 for address 192.168.1.125, but it was not available.  This usually means that some other process is listening on this port already.  You can check with `netstat -tnp | grep 6879`, or change the ejabberd configuration to use a different port.

Alternatively, it can mean that the IP address doesn't belong to the machine ejabberd is running on.

Comment: No result. `lsof -i` also shows that port 6879 is unoccupied. I am running the CentOS on a VM on my mac 10.9

Comment: I would rather check if ip address 192.168.1.125 is correct

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by disabling the mod_proxy65 module. Co-worker had enabled it for file transfer but with a differed i.p address.